My JAVA_HOME value is invalid and I have been unable to change it
I am currently working on a react-native project and I get this error while trying to run yarn android.
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Users/olamidembp/.jenv/versions/system

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Here are some details that can help with debugging.
When I run javac -version I get this output javac 17.0.9
This is the content of my ~/.zshrc
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export GEM_HOME="$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
export PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"

I have tried setting the JAVA_HOME to several values using different methods but it doesn't change.
I want to be able to use the Java 17 I have installed to run yarn android

You can check where Java is installed by running:
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17

